# How to create a submit button that will disable in previous page after the submit button in current page is submitted?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, button

I have this main page where user enters date and goes to second page, 
The user enters the date and click submit, once I click submit,the form is 
submitted and in the previous page(which is the main page) the submit button is disabled.

How to create a submit button that will disable in previous page after the submit button in current page is submitted?

below is code for test2.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<header><h4>Customer Purchase Order</h4></header>
<form action="test3.php" method="post">
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;" width="500" height="206" border="1">
  Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="sdate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" onclick="myFunction()"><br><br>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled = true;
}
</script>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is code for test3.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a href="test2.php">Back</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You appear to have supplied code for only one page...

Comment: @GrishaLevit I hv edited my post by adding the second page code

Comment: Your question is somehow unclear. What is the relation between these two pages? In page  `test2.php` when you submit the form, you navigate tp another page `test3.php`, But in this page you do not have any form and thus do not have any submit button. Also you do not have any element with `id=mySubmit` in your first page. And then even if you had a submit button in your second page, How are you supposed to seethe content of the first page? I just can see a link to first page in the second page. Please elaborate more on your question...

Comment: I would agree with EhsanT and add that there is no actual PHP code in the example that you provided.  Also, If your trying to run a javascript function from your submit button then I would recommend using `input type="button"` rather than `input type="submit"`.